# Comparing wrapper class with primitive using equals() gives strange behavior

Tags: java, wrapper, equals

Consider below code snap.
we use `equals()` to compare objects are meaningfully equivalent or not ?
Here both value are meaningfully equal but why does `longWrapper.equals(0)` return `false` ?
And when I compared both value with `==` operator it returns `true`.

```
    Long longWrapper = 0L;
    long longPrimitive = 0;

    System.out.println(longWrapper == 0L); // true
    System.out.println(longWrapper == 0); //true
    System.out.println(longWrapper == longPrimitive); //true


    System.out.println(longWrapper.equals(0L)); //true
    System.out.println(longWrapper.equals(0));  //false
    System.out.println(longWrapper.equals(longPrimitive)); //true
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`longWrapper.equals(0)` returns `false`, because `0` is autoboxed to `Integer`, not to `Long`. Since the two types are different, `.equals()` returns `false`.

In the meantime, `longWrapper == 0` is `true`, because the `longwrapper` value is unboxed to `0`, and `0 == 0` without considering the actual primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

Its because 0 is not a long - its an int, and wrappers don't convert Integer's to Long's

Answer (score 2):

When you compare `0 == 0L`, you're comparing an `int` literal to a `long` literal. The `int` gets [**promoted**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) to a `long`, and then their values are compared. Since both are zeroes, the result is `true`.

When you add autoboxing to the mix, things are slightly different. A primitive is always autoboxed to its wrapper type. Here, `0`, which is an `int` literal, is autoboxed to a `java.lang.Integer` wrapper instance. Since `java.lang.Long` and `java.lang.Integer` are different classes, `equals` between them must return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(0L == 0)` is `True`.

so `longWrapper == 0` which unboxed and result is `True`. 

And in `Long.equals` written as -

```
781     public boolean More ...equals(Object obj) {
782         if (obj instanceof Long) {
783             return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
784         }
785         return false;
786     }
```

so `System.out.println(longWrapper.equals(0));` return false as 0 will be boxed in `Integer` and `if (obj instanceof Long)` is false.

Answer (score 1):

This one:

```
System.out.println(longWrapper == 0);
```

is comparing with `==`, so it unboxes your `Long`, and you are comparing two primitives, both of which are zero.

This one:

```
System.out.println(longWrapper.equals(0));
```

is comparing with `equals`, so it boxes up the (`int`) zero as an `Integer`. A `Long` object is never equal to an `Integer` object, even if they are holding the same number.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the 0 in the equals method is an Integer. When you define the longPrimitive with 0 this 0 is casted to a long-value. the equals method accepts all objects and because of this the 0 stays an integer and is not casted. My guess is that in the equals method there is a call if the given object is an instance of long and since this 0 is an Integer it results in false.
I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

The equals method of Long explains why

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Long.java#Long.equals%28java.lang.Object%29

There is line there

```
 if (obj instanceof Long) {
```

longWrapper.equals(0) the paramter would become of type Integer.

On the other hand longWrapper.equals(longPrimitive) will box the pameter into Long

Answer (score 0):

From `Long.java` class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So when you compare a `Long` to an `int` using equals, the `if` condition fails and the method returns `false`.

The other methods return `true` due to [autoboxing and unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)